# Angularjs ng-model for checkbox input

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel

I'm having a bit of trouble with `ng-model`. The function `checkshow()` is called whenever an option from the select box is selected. Depending on which buttons are selected it should call the function in the condition.

```
   $scope.checkshow=function(item) {
                    alert(item);
                    var Name=item;
                    if ($scope.radioSelected === 'radiobutton1')
                    {   $scope.show(Name);
                        $scope.showfeature(Name);

                    }
                    else if($scope.radioSelected === 'radiobutton2' && $scope.checkboxed1 === 'detailchecked'){
                        alert("detail");
                        $scope.showDetails(Name);

                        }
                    else if($scope.radioSelected === 'radiobutton2' && $scope.checkboxed2 === 'comparechecked'){
                        alert("Surprise");
                      }

                else{
                    $scope.showS(Name);
                }

                };
```

Only the `if` and `else` conditions are working, it never enters the `else if` part .

```
<input type="checkbox" id="chck1" disabled value="detailchecked" ng-model="checkboxed1">Detailed                          
    <input type="checkbox" id="chck2" disabled value="comparechecked" ng-model="checkboxed2">Compare</label></td></tr>
```

There are 2 radiobuttions 1 and 2. I didn't write their code because conditions on them are working.

Comment: can you provide the plunkr for this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The model of a checkbox is a **boolean**: if the checkbox with `ng-model="checkboxed1"` is chceked, then `$scope.checkboxed1` is set to true, otherwise it's set to false.

But you're comparing it to `'detailchecked'`, so that comparison will always be false.

Read the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bcheckbox%5D): it explains how it works and has examples.

Comment: You're awesome! . I should learn to read the documentation carefully .